# Focus highlighting thumbnails

Tags: focus

Is there any software that will analyze the photos in a directory and create thumbnails with the areas most in focus highlighted in color? I know my camera (Sony a99ii) can do this real time.

It would be pretty useful, especially when working with burst shots to quickly pick the ones that focused properly without having to open them all.